# How to calculate output dimensions in CNN if you specify number of outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am having trouble figuring out what the dimensions of each `CNN` layer is.

Let's say my input is a vector which I then projected onto a `4x4x256` matrix using a fully-connected layer as so...

```
zP = slim.fully_connected(
    z,
    4*4*256,
    normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
    scope='g_project',
    weights_initializer=initializer
)

# Layer is reshaped to a 4x4x256 mapping.
zCon = tf.reshape(zP,[-1,4,4,256])
```

Where `z` was my original vector. I then take this `4x4x256` matrix and feed it into a `CNN`...

```
gen1 = slim.convolution2d_transpose(
    zCon,
    num_outputs=64,
    kernel_size=[5,5],
    stride=[2,2],
    padding="SAME",
    normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
    scope='g_conv1', 
    weights_initializer=initializer
)
```

As you can see I used a convolutional 2d transpose and I specified the output as *64*, with a stride of *2* and a filter size of *5*. This means that I know one of my dimension will be *64*, however I do not know what the other 2 dimensions will be and I do not know how to calculate it.

I tried using the following formula but it is not working out for me...

[image]

How can I calculate the remaining dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you have written is for the Convolution operation, since you need to calculate for the `transposed convolution` where the shapes are inverse of convolution, the formula can be derived from the above equation by re-arranging the terms as:

`W = (Out-1)*S + F - 2P`

`W` is your actual output and `Out` is your actual input to the `transpose convolution`.